# Dart: Api call using Stream instead of Future

Tags: flutter, dart, future

How to do API call in Flutter using *Stream* function instead of *Future* function, Not looking for StreamBuilder.

Api call using future

```dart
Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
  final response =
      await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');

  return response;
}
```

I want to do the same above function using Stream

Comment: `Not looking for StreamBuilder` - so do you want to use `StreamBuilder` or not?

Comment: I want to call api in initState() so can't use StreamBuilder..

Comment: Future was like either response or error .. if i got error(like Socket Exception) then Future would stop listening, I don't want my Future function to stop listening until i get the response i want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116525/flutter-handle-api-response-after-exception .. this is what i want.. !! would you help me!!

Comment: so rebuilt your widget by calling `setState` and call your api again

Comment: try Stream.fromFuture(http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'))

Comment: @pskink i am calling api inside initstate() so rebuilding widget doesn't do any good..Even tried catchError() but no luck

Comment: @JerryZhou i give it a try and let u know

Comment: ya.. able to get it done by calling the basefunction of the Future recursively inside catchError() using setState().. thanks @pskink .. I done this before too but that time called future function instead of base function inside catchError().. so the future keep on called !!

Comment: i have no idea what "base function" you mean...

Comment: `initApiCall(context) {
    _getSomeDetailsFromApiCall(context).then((response) {
      showLog('response: $response');
    }).catchError((error){
      setState(() {
        initApiCall(context);
      });
    });
  }`

Answer (score 2):

please checkout dio http package

https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Comment: Please give better responses. The `dio` package is huge and OP probably knows about its existence. OP is probable looking for a solution which is not highlighted in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not an expert, but I handled that way:

```
Stream <bool> _syncData(int dataType) async*{
  while(true){
  HttpResult<List<Object>?> httpResult = await  //your request goes here... ;
  if (httpResult.status != HttpStatus.ok) {
     yield false;
  }
yield true;
 }}
```